# Не выводит кириллицу в текстовый файл .txt

Tags: delphi

Пишу на delphi 10.3, не знаю, почему выводит непонятные символы, вместо букв на кириллице. Помогите пожалуйста. Сам код:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, windows;

var
 a:array [1..3,1..3] of ANSIchar;
 i, j:integer;
 f1, f2: textfile;


begin
  setconsolecp(1251);
  setconsoleoutputcp(1251);
  assignfile(f1, paramstr(1));
  assignfile(f2, paramstr(2));
  reset(f1);
  rewrite(f2);
  for i := 1 to 3 do
    begin
      for j := 1 to 3 do
        read(f1, a[i,j]);
      readln(f1);
    end;
  for i := 1 to 3 do
    begin
      for j := 1 to 3 do
        write(f2, a[i,j],' ');
      writeln(f2);
    end;
  closefile(f1);
  closefile(f2);
end.
```

Comment: В последние 10 лет почти всегда используют unicode (UTF-8). У вас используется ANSIchar, а текстовый файл на входе точно содержит однобайтную кодировку?

Comment: @VladChapl, windows чаще использует UTF-16, а не UTF-8

Comment: @danny, покажите пример содержимого входного и выходного файлов

Comment: @ГерманБорисов на вход программе подается матрица 3x3 из элементов (а). Должен вывести эту самую матрицу

Comment: @danny, это понятно по коду. Если вы покажете сами «непонятные символы», и как они выглядели изначально, шанс что вам ответят будет выше.

Answer (score 0):

Можно посмотреть какая кодировка файла (например с помощью Notepad++), который передается в первом аргументе и явно установить тип кодировки при обращении к файлу.

Например для `utf-8` будет работать следующее:

```
...
AssignFile(f1, paramstr(1), CP_UTF8);
...
```

Также можно воспользоваться `Stream` для работы с файлами. [Вот еще примеры](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14243866/2546083)

Если не ошибаюсь `setconsolecp` и `setconsoleoutputcp` поможет только при выводе в консоль, Вы же работаете с файлом напрямую.